# Centralise div with minimum left margin

Tags: html, css

I am building a web site which has a navigation bar at the top. This bar consists of a logo in the top left corner, and a toolbar centralised in the window, as below. The logo is just an img tag with `position:absolute` to put it in the correct position, and the toolbar is a div with `width:100%` and the components centralised within it.

[image]

If the window is resized too small, or on tablet devices if the device is rotated to portrait, the toolbar overlaps the logo, like this:

[image]

I want the toolbar to stop moving when it reaches the logo, so if the window were resized it would like this:

[image]

I did find this solution:

[css: how to build centered div with minimum spacing on the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927854/css-how-to-build-centered-div-with-minimum-spacing-on-the-left)

But the problem with this was that it relied on knowing the width of the centralised component (the toolbar), which cannot be guaranteed in this particular situation.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: If you want the toolbar to stop moving when it reaches the logo, then you really need to set the logo position to `relative` at that point so that you bring it **back into the flow of the document** - otherwise, as far as the toolbar is concerned, the logo may as well not even be there, it has no relation to that element's position in the document flow.

Comment: _“Toolbar is a div with width:100%”_ ? 100% of what? Looking at your screenshots it seems an element with an absolute-unit width/max-width

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both the logo and toolbar to {position: relative}. Then you need to set the toolbar to:

```
.toolbar {position: relative; float: right;}
```

and the logo to:

```
img {position: relative; float: left}
```

When the page is resized this should make them not overlap one another. You may also want to look into making a 'burger menu' for when the page is reduced past a certain point. I'd recommend doing this with media queries.

See the below Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dbcv4yc7/

If you want your topbar to be central, then you'll need to put it into a div which takes up the rest of the right space.

Such as:

```
.logo {position: relative; float: left; width:30%; background-color: red}
.topbar {margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; width:50%;background-color:red;}
.topbarContainer {float:right; width: 70%}
```

Please see the below Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dbcv4yc7/1/